# Excel to choose all possible combinations

Tags: excel, combinations, vba

I've been trying to create this spreadsheet for days, but I'm just not sure on how to approach the final part of it, so I'm hoping someone on here will be able to help me.

To give you some context I'm trying optimize how many pallets of certain products we can fit onto a truck. Some pallets weigh more than others and some are much more common than others. We always put 24 pallets on, but if we were to combine with other less common products that weight less we could fit on 25 (or possibly even 26).

I need to create a spreadsheet where the user enters an amount of a certain item (product A which is the most common) and it gives all the possible combinations of the other products that could go with it that keeps it under a certain weight.

So for example. The user says they need to send out 17 of product A. It would then give you all the combinations that could fit with those 17 that keeps it below weight and at 25 (or 26) in total.

If it helps here at the actual weights below:

```
Product A = 1.138
Product B = 1.009776
Product C = 1.089
Product D = 1.092
Product E = 0.86556
```

Maximum weight is 28.

Is anyone help to help me achieve this?

[I've found this document](https://www.excelforum.com/attachments/excel-general/461236d1463506035-have-total-want-to-know-what-adds-up-to-it-find_sum.xlsm) but this excel sheet doesn't aim to add up to 25 (or 26) which I want. I also don't need it to add up to 28, just be less than 28.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem because such a problem could only exist if there was a logic of what to program. Figure out the logic and we might help you express it in code. But at that point someone here (perhaps myself) would ask where is the code you tried to create yourself. So, this question faces some serious problems with site rule compliance.

Comment: ^^ it's the knapsak problem, but you seem to want to solve it by brute force, which is ok for small scale problems. But then you need to start your own effort before asking for help.

Comment: Ok, if I've broken site rules I apologise. I'm not really sure where to begin as I've got a sheet that does a knapsack problem but nothing like I want it. I shall, however, come up with something before asking again. Just out of interest what do you mean solve by brute force?

Comment: By Brute force I mean by trying all possible combinations, as you wrote in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem in a similar situation, I needed to optimize the way the logistics load the trucks. I haven't applied any of this yet, but I found this [Spreadsheet](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/knapsack-problem.html) for the knapsak problem. Between all values you pass to the sheet, the VBA get as many as possible values that fits the limit you also pass.

This spreadsheet is limited to 5 weights, but you might be capable to make it receive N weights.